# Using RegExp function

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I am a newbie to HTML and JavaScript. We are trying to validate the IP address using the below regular expression using the RegExp function. But the problem with this regular expression is that is validating and returning true, for invalid IP addresses as well.

For example the regular expression works correctly when IP address is entered as `10.94.161.125` but it is returning true when the IP address is entered as `10/94/161/125`.

In fact, any character in the place of `.` (like `@`, `!`, `#` etc) is not making the function to return false, but instead it is returning true. Please do let me know as what is the exact difference "\." is making in order to make the regular expression work correctly, where as "." it is not making regular expression work in a correct way. This is where I need clarification.

Regular expression non-working case senario:

```
var ipRE = new RegExp( '^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}$' );
```

Regular expression working case senario

```
var ipRE = new RegExp( '^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}$' );
```

Comment: The regex you show does not expose the problem you describe. Post the code you are *actually* using, even better, try to spot the difference yourself first.

Comment: This regular expressions works perfectly.

Comment: So you *actually had* working code and now paste broken code just so you can ask a question? What is that supposed to accomplish? And why are you not asking the question you really want to ask?

Comment: I pasted the working code by mistake, when I posted the question for the first time. I was trying to find out the difference as how the extra "\\." is making the problem to resolve.

Comment: Read about character escaping in JavaScript strings and in regular expressions. You seem to be missing a very basic concept and should not go on using regex without understanding it first.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, if anyone comes here looking for a answer:

> The backslash (\) can be used to insert apostrophes, new lines,
>   quotes, and other special characters into a string.

Example:

```
var str = 'You\'re welcome';
```

without escaping the `'`, the string would terminate after `You`

In your regular expression, the dot needs to be escaped, since a dot have special meaning in regular expression. The backslash then needs to be escaped, because it has a special meaning in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
ValidIpAddressRegex = "^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$";
```

and :

```
ValidHostnameRegex = "^(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$";
```

Comment: A regex of that complexity posted without any explanation or context hardly counts as an answer.